# Simulate data from a Gompertz curve in R

Tags: r

I have a set of data that I have collected which consists of a time series, where each y-value is found by taking the mean of 30 samples of grape cluster weight.

I want to simulate more data from this, with the same number of x and y values, so that I can carry out some Bayesian analysis to find the posterior distribution of the data.
I have the data, and I know that the growth follows a Gompertz curve with formula:

`[y = a*exp(-exp(-(x-x0)/b))]`, with `a = 88.8`, `b = 11.7`, and `x0 = 15.1`.

The data I have is

```
x = c(0, 28, 36, 42, 50, 58, 63, 71, 79, 85, 92, 99, 106, 112)

y = c(0, 15, 35, 55, 62, 74, 80, 96, 127, 120, 146, 160, 177, 165).
```

Any help would be appreciated thank you

Answer (score 0):

*Will edit when more information is given**

I am a little confused by your question. I have compiled what you have written into R. Please elaborate for me so that I can help you:

```
gompertz <- function(x, x0, a, b){
  a*exp(-exp(-(x-x0)/b))
}

y = c(0, 15, 35, 55, 62, 74, 80, 96, 127, 120, 146, 160, 177, 165) # means of 30 samples of grape cluster weights?
x = c(0, 28, 36, 42, 50, 58, 63, 71, 79, 85, 92, 99, 106, 112) # ?

#??
gompertz(x, x0 = 15.1, a = 88.8, b = 11.7)
gompertz(y, x0 = 15.1, a = 88.8, b = 11.7)
```

Comment: Freidland x refers to the days from fruit set (i.e. 0 is when the time series starts) x values only correspond to the days in which the measurements are taken (which depends on certain growth stages of grapes). Effectively what I need is to simulate data which follows the Gompertz curve. And when I have this data, and have created the posterior distribution, I will use it as a predictive model of sorts to determine how well it has predicted the time series data I have provided. Does this help you at all?